# I have deserialized C# class and i want to save it sqlite using xamarin forms PCL

Tags: c#, sqlite, deserialization, xamarin.forms

The deserialized class need to be store locally in sqlite database.

I am  using xamarin forms PCL , the metadata need to save and retrieve locally in database.

I am not able to understand how can we save the deserialized C# class into database.

Comment: Hi, Have you given this sample code a look??? https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo/PCL/Todo

Comment: I have already. But my concern now is to generate database columns from my desrialize object.

Comment: **Here Data is deserialized object.** 
**database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();**
//create table if not exists in database
**database.CreateTable <Data> ();**

Comment: Use CreateTable<T>. If the object has other than supported data members it will fail unless you use the IBlobSerializer interface (assuming you use SQLite.Net.Async) in which case the unsupported types are serialized as byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, using CreateTable will handle that for you. Taking from the Xamarin.Forms sample:

```cs
public TodoItemDatabase()
{
    database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();
    // create the tables
    database.CreateTable<TodoItem>();
}
```

Now you have the table to save to. You would call it like any other ORM:

```
public int SaveItem (TodoItem item)
{
    lock (locker) {
        if (item.ID != 0) {
            database.Update(item);
            return item.ID;
        } else {
            return database.Insert(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to worry about the specifics assuming you are using the Sqlite ORM wrapper: SQLite.Net-PCL nicely available from Nuget.