# xamarin.forms Storing and retrieving image files using sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

Currently i working in storing images (using ImageSource element) in sqlite. I am reading files from local directory after that i trying to storing 
the images into sqlite but i can't able to store the images . can any one help me to store. also how to convert image source as bytes in xamarin.forms

Here my code snap

```
Interface
 Task<Product> AddToDo(string title, string subtitle,ImageSource img);

Calling method
ImageFile = ImageSource.FromFile("Chinese_6_600_C.jpg");

await azureService.AddToDo(Title, Subtitle, ImageFile);


public async Task<Product> AddToDo(string title, string subtitle, ImageSource img)

{

await Initialize();

 var item = new Product     
{

Title=title,

Subtitle=subtitle,

 ImageFile= img

 };


//TODO 5: Insert item into todoTable

await todoTable.InsertAsync(item);

//Synchronize todos

await SyncToDos();

return item;

 }
```

Here i have imported the nuget packages `'( Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore)'` for storing data between sqlite and azure cloud store.
When i inserting imagesource into `' (await todoTable.InsertAsync(item)'`it was not accepting. Please help me For handling this situation

Comment: stackoverflow is for concrete, specific answers to well-defined problems, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  It's not for very broad questions such as yours.  Start writing your app, and when you are stuck on something specific, then ask for help.  By simply Googling for [xamarin forms save to sqlite](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=xamarin+forms+save+to+sqlite) I found https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/ and also http://stackoverflow.com/q/26418449/3744182.

Comment: team please accept my question.